# Can't retrieve image in image control via image handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, handler

I am successfully able to store image in database but I am unable to retrieve it...

I have database `ImageDatabase` with a single table `Pict` that contains two columns `Letter` (`varchar(50)`) (pk) and `Picture` (`image`),

My `Handler.ashx` code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string L = (context.Request.QueryString["Letter"]);       
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=RANJHANI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial        Catalog=ImageDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
    string sql = "SELECT Picture FROM Pict WHERE Letter = @Ltr";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ltr", L);
    connection.Open();
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);        
    connection.Close();
}   

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

my default.aspx

```
<img id="img1" src="Handler.ashx?Letter='a'" />
```

Please do help me in this regard, where i am making mistake,

Comment: What do you get when request `Handler.ashx?Letter='a'` in the browser?

Comment: nothing brother, my image does not load,
a red cross icon on image controle.

Comment: Please check the result by firebug or chrome developer tool, Do you get 200 OK or 500 Internal error

Comment: at highliting <img> 
it says failed to load given url

Answer (score 0):

Try clear response stream before to the BinaryWrite

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Still receiving same problem

Comment: Set a break point on `context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);` and check bytes length